# Is helping out a relative without salary considered a job?

Tags: job-description, employment, law

One of my friends is helping out his uncle in his business without getting paid and his uncle gave him a place to stay for free. Is it considered a job?

Comment: I'm aware your question is not about the legal aspect of this cooperation, but I'll advise to check them, just in case. It seems legally borderline and you should check if it is legal to do so in your country.

Comment: All law questions require you to specify the country. It would also be helpful to specify what aspect your are interested in: experience, taxes, minimum wages...

Comment: In the UK this definitely counts as receiving benefits, thus "getting paid", as he has a place to stay. And it's not for free, he's working for it. What is your friend's locale?

Comment: Is this just curiosity on your part, or is it relevant whether he "has a job" (because maybe he is collecting government assistance)? That might help focus the answers. Also please note that this isn't the best SE for employment law questions.

Comment: *Is it considered a job?* - this depends on who is defining **a job.** Do you mean *should he put it on his resume?* Or do you mean, *should he be paying income tax?* Or do you mean, *do labor laws apply?* or do you mean, *can he collect unemployment?* Or something else?

Comment: @dwizum do labor laws apply?

Answer (score 4):

### That depends on a lot of factors

and the country definitely matters here. In my country (Denmark) he is considered to be working if:

- The wage he should earn (Not the one he is earning) under normal circumstances reaches a certain size.
- He is getting financial aid for beeing unemployeed.
- He is educated within the area he's helping (e.g. a carpenter helping with carpentry related tasks).

So in conclusion, ask over at a stack exchange focused on legal advice and maybe even consider asking a public worker/lawyer in your native country. They might be able to guide you better.

Comment: Also the same circumstances could be evaluated differently depending of the context (who is doing the distinction and why): maybe some activities are not considered work for getting credits at school, but they are considered work if you are trying to ask a visitor visa or if you want to claim unemployment benefits.

Comment: Definitelity, there are a lot of factors for sure.